# Object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' cannot be converted to type

Tags: c#, json, xna, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to parse some data into some particular properties using reflection.

`property.SetValue(comInstance, field.Value);`

one this line it throws an `ArgumentException`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2'.

I know this must have something to do with my `JsonConverter` for `Vector2` types, which looks like this:

```
public class Vector2Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Vector2));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = jsonObject.Properties().ToList();
        return new Vector2
        {
            X = (float)properties[0].Value,
            Y = (float)properties[1].Value
        };
    }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Vector2 v = (Vector2)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("X");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, v.X);
        writer.WritePropertyName("Y");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, v.Y);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        
    }
}
```

now, I noticed that write gets called, but read never does.
I deserialize like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityJson>(json, JsonUtility.Settings);
```

the `JsonUility.Settings` contain the `Vector2Converter`.

and I serialize like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entityJson, Formatting.Indented, JsonUtility.Settings);
```

The field in the JSON itself looks good as well:

```
"Center": {
      "X": 116.0,
      "Y": 65.0
    },
```

Can anyone help me out?

Edit:

```
internal class EntityJson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ComponentJson> Components { get; set; }
    
    public EntityJson()
    {
        Components = new Dictionary<string, ComponentJson>();
    }

    public Entity ToEntity()
    {
        Entity entity = new Entity(Name);

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, ComponentJson> com in Components)
        {
            ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance(com.Value.Namespace, com.Value.Namespace +"."+ com.Key);
            Object handleValue = handle.Unwrap();
            Component comInstance = (Component)handleValue;

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> field in com.Value.Fields)
            {
                PropertyInfo property = comInstance.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key, 
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                    BindingFlags.Public | 
                    BindingFlags.Instance);

                property.SetValue(comInstance, field.Value); // <-- field.Value
            }

            entity.AddUnsafe(comInstance);
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

the field.value will be a `JObject` instead of a `Vector2`, the exception states:

> it cannot be casted.

Comment: Is the JSON converter throwing the exception?  I don't see the line of code `property.SetValue(comInstance, field.Value);` anywhere in the converter.

Comment: What does your `EntityJson` class look like?  Does the property name of the Vector2 in that class match the property name in the JSON that you are deserializing?

Comment: You need to show us the code where `property.SetValue(comInstance, field.Value);` is called.  But if `field.Value` is a `JObject`, and you are inside some higher level JSON converter, you need to convert it to the target type, for instance with [`JToken.ToObject Method (Type, JsonSerializer)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject_1.htm)

Comment: this is what my EntityJson looks like:

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ive managed to resolve it doing this:

```
object result = field.Value;
if (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(JObject))
{
      JToken token = (JToken)field.Value;
      result = token.ToObject(property.PropertyType, JsonSerializer.Create(JsonUtility.Settings));
}
else
{
      result = Convert.ChangeType(result, property.PropertyType);
}

property.SetValue(comInstance, result);
```

Is this a stable solution ?

Comment: If you are trying to apply JSON fragments to a pre-existing object, you can use [JsonConvert.PopulateObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject_1.htm) and let Json.NET do the reflection for you.

Comment: _"Is this a **stable** solution ?"_ - that's arguably a **new** _question_

Comment: @MickyDuncan: And one that sounds just a bit closer to [CodeReview.SE] than SO.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thx Nathan, was not aware of that sub site

Comment: oh sorry, first question I asked here probably if I remember correctly. Ill keep it in mind, thanks.